# Usando C# 6.0 no VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Tenho o Visual Studio 2010 instalado. Gostaria de saber se é possível usar os recursos da versão 6.0 do C# na minha IDE

Answer (score 2):

Infelizmente você não poderá utilizar os recursos do C# 6 no VS 2010. Se fosse ao menos o VS 2012.

Acompanhe a evolução da linguagem

### Versões atuais

- **C# 7.1** -> VS2017 *versão 15.3* || .NET Core 2.0
- `async` main, inferência de nome de membro de tupla, expressão padrão, correspondência de padrões com `generics`.
- **C# 7** -> VS2017 || .NET Core 1.0 e posteriores
- Principais: tuplas, ref locals e ref return, correspondência de padrões (incluindo instruções de comutação baseadas em padrões), declarações de parâmetros `out`, funções locais, literais binários, separadores de dígitos e retornos arbitrários assíncronos.
- **C# 6** -> VS2015 .NET 4.6 || .NET Core 1.0
- Implementado pelo Roslyn. Inicializadores para propriedades implementadas automaticamente, usando diretrizes para importar membros estáticos, filtros de exceção, membros indexados e inicializadores de elementos, `await` em `catch` e `finally`, método de extensão `Add` em inicializadores de coleções.

### Versões anteriores

A seguir estão listados as principais funcionalidades que foram introduzidas em versões anteriores da linguagem C# e Visual Studio .NET.

- **C# 5** -> VS2013

  - Esta versão do Visual Studio incluiu correções de bug, aprimoramentos de desempenho e visualizações de tecnologia da Plataforma do Compilador .NET ("Roslyn");
- **C# 5** -> VS2012 .NET 4.5 (4.7)

  - Async/await, atributos de informações do chamador;

  Para direcionar para o .NET Framework 4.7 no Visual Studio 2012 ou posterior, instale o [Pacote do Desenvolvedor do Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=55168).
- **C# 4** -> VS2010 .NET 4

  - Dynamic, argumentos nomeados, parâmetros opcionais e covariância e contravariância genéricas;
- **C# 3** -> VS2008 .NET 3.5

  - Inicializadores de objeto e coleção, expressões lambda, métodos de extensão, tipos anônimos, propriedades automáticas, inferência de tipos var local e LINQ (Consulta Integrada à Linguagem);
- **C# 2** -> VS2005 .NET 2.0

  - Métodos anônimos, genéricos, tipos anuláveis, iteradores/suspensão, classes static, covariância e contravariância para delegados;
- **C# 1.1** -> VS2003

  - Comentários da documentação XML e pragma #line;
- **C# 1** -> VS2002 .NET 1.0

  - A primeira versão do C#.